# Is the phrase 'request you to send the copy' correct?

Tags: grammaticality, subcontinental-english

I read in this website that *request* should be with *that* and a clause, not the one with a *to*-infinitive. In that sense the phrase *Request you to send the copy* seems to be wrong. If its wrong what would be correct way?

Comment: The elision of the subject bugs me.

Comment: Generally, you have to _request that_ somebody does something. The version you found is incorrect. At the very least, it needs to be changed to _requesting_.

Comment: No that does not sound right. You should **request that somebody *do* something**.

Answer (score 2):

"I request you to send me a copy of the report" is incorrect.

"I request that you send me a copy of the report" is correct.

Request and ask nearly mean the same thing; however, they are not interchangeable as they are used differently.

Comment: Hi none. I edited your answer to add line breaks. Can you please explain why the first is incorrect and the second is incorrect. The answer isn't very useful as it is.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *request* can be used with a clause to politely ask for something, and with an infinitive to politely ask someone to do something.

[Here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/request) is a reference to Oxford Dictionaries Online along with a number of usage examples.

> **Request** 
>   *verb* 
>   [WITH OBJECT] 
>   1. Politely or formally ask for: 
>   [WITH CLAUSE]: *'The chairman requested that the reports be considered.'* 
>   
>   1.1 [WITH INFINITIVE] Politely or formally ask (someone) to do something:
>   *'The letter requested him to report to London.'*

*I request you to send me a copy of the report* is grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use (to + infinitive). Not that I have an English degree or something. But I've searched the web and found that it used a lot.
Also it doesn't sound wrong at all, and we always use it in our conversations.